# Page Objects in Selenium with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm familiar with Page Objects in Watir-Webdriver using Ruby, but now i'm trying to define Page Objects in Selenium-Webdriver with Ruby and facing the below issue. Could any one please help.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "page-object"

Firstname = {id: "firstname"}

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@driver.get ("http://www.practiceselenium.com/practice-form.html")
@driver.manage().window.maximize()
@driver.find_element(Firstname).send_keys "User1"
```

Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"firstname"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `id: "firstname"` attribute on the page you specified. Try `name: "firstname"` instead:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "page-object"

Firstname = {name: "firstname"}

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@driver.get ("http://www.practiceselenium.com/practice-form.html")
@driver.manage().window.maximize()
@driver.find_element(Firstname).send_keys "User1"
```

Or in a more object oriented fashion:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "page-object"

class PraticeForm
  include PageObject

  page_url "http://www.practiceselenium.com/practice-form.html"
  text_field(:firstname, :name => 'firstname')
end

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
my_page_object = PraticeForm.new(browser)
my_page_object.goto

my_page_object.firstname = "User1"
```